# Laravel - How to resolve Rule Request Validation Error

Tags: laravel

I have this Project in Laravel-5.8 that validates:

goal_type_id, appraisal_identity_id, employee_id as unique in appraisal_goals using Rule Request.

goal_type_id, appraisal_identity_id, employee_id are foreign keys

Model

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'goal_type_id',
              'appraisal_identity_id',
              'employee_id',
              'company_id',
          ];
```

StoreAppraisalGoalReques

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'goal_type_id' => [
            'required',              
            Rule::unique('appraisal_goals', 'goal_type_id', 'appraisal_identity_id', 'employee_id')
        ],       

    ];
} 

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'goal_type_id.required'                 => 'Please enter the Goal Type!',
        'goal_type_id.unique'                   => 'Goal Type already exists. Please enter a unique Goal Type.!',
    ];
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(StoreAppraisalGoalRequest $request)
{

    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $employeeId = Auth::user()->employee_id;
      $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id','appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    try {
        $goal = new AppraisalGoal();
        $goal->goal_type_id             = $request->goal_type_id;
        $goal->appraisal_identity_id    = $request->appraisal_identity_id;
        $goal->employee_id              = $employeeId;  
        $goal->is_active                = 1;               
        $goal->save();

        foreach ( $request->activity as $key => $activity){

            $goaldetail = new AppraisalGoalDetail();

            $goaldetail->kpi_description            = $request->kpi_description[$key];
            $goaldetail->appraisal_doc              = $request->application_doc[$key];
            $goaldetail->activity                   = $request->activity[$key];  
            $goaldetail->start_date                 = $startDate ->toDateTimeString();
            $goaldetail->end_date                   = $endDate->toDateTimeString();                 
            $goaldetail->save();
         }

            Session::flash('success', 'Appraisal Goal is created successfully');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Session::flash('danger', 'Appraisal Goal creation failed!');
            return redirect()->route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index');
    }
}
```

An employee can only have one goal_type_id relating to appraisal_identity_id and employee_id in the appraisal_goals table.

Employee a successfully did this. But when another employee logs in and submit, I got this error:

Goal Type already exists. Please enter a unique Goal Type.!

Note this doesn't exist.

as shown in the rules validation custom message:

How do I resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Rule::unique()` will be applying to only `'goal_type_id'` but is referencing an array of your unique columns.

If you are looking to make sure they are unique values within their respective tables, do something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'goal_type_id' => 'required|unique:goal_types,id',
        'employee_id' => 'required|unique:employees,id',
        ...
    ];
}
```

---

**Composite Key validation** [laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique)

What you are lookjing for is validation of composite key (i.e. they are unique in combination). This can be achieved using the `where` constraints

```
'goal_type_id' => Rule::unique('goal_types')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query
        ->where('employee_id', 1)
        ->where('appraisal_identity_id', 1);
})
```

Comment: Its like you don't understand. These three fields are unique together in relation to goal_type_id. That is, when a goal_type_id is entered the application must check it in relation to appraisal_identity_id and employee_id in appraisal_goals table

Comment: As i suspected then, you are wanting to check a composite key is unique. The fact you had your rule against `goal_type_id` threw me a bit.

Comment: I've updated my answer but I haven't had chance to test it but it should point you in the right direction!

Comment: How do I now do the one for update.                 'goal_type_id' => [
                'required',              
                Rule::unique('appraisal_goals', 'goal_type_id', 'appraisal_identity_id', 'employee_id')->ignore($this->appraisal_goal)
            ],